# Applying the NOT operator to a very large binary number ( 1011111111000000000011111111110000000000111111111100000000001111111111)

Tags: c#, binary, bitwise-operators, not-operator

```cs
static string ReturnValueIfInputOneIsThree(string inputOne, string input)
{
    string result = "";
    if (CheckIfInputOneIsInACorrectFormatOrNot(inputOne, input) && inputOne == "3")
    {
        for (var i = 0; i < input.Length; i++)
        {
            if (input[i] == '0')
            {
                result += "1";
            }
            else if (input[i] == '1')
            {
                result += "0";
            }
        }

        var finalResult = Convert.ToIn64(result, 2);
        return finalResult.ToString();
    }

    return ThisReturnValuInMain(inputOne, input);
}
```

If I introduce a number in base 2 and I apply the not operator, for example ~00110001 or ~10 , I got the correct result, but when I Introduce a very large binary number like:

1011111111000000000011111111110000000000111111111100000000001111111111 the result is not “100000000111111111100000000001111111111000000000011111111110000000000”.

I tried to use BigInteger, but the module from the course doesn't let me to use it, so I have to solve the problem in another way.

Do you have any suggestion how to solve this problem without BigInteger?

Comment: `Convert.ToInt64` is surely wrong, as you have more than 64 bits. Are you sure you're supposed to return the *decimal* value from this operation? Seeing as you're complaining it's not returning a binary one I mean...

Comment: yes I realized it, because I debugged...Do you have any suggestion?

Comment: If you checked the `result` inside the method you would've seen that it contains `"0100000000111111111100000000001111111111000000000011111111110000000000"`, exactly the number you wanted, just with a leading zero (which you can trim away if needs be). You could do `return result.TrimStart('0');` instead of the int64 conversion.

Comment: I will try this, thank you!

Comment: I solved it like this, thank you so much @LasseV.Karlsen .

Answer (score 0):

The problem lies with

> 1011111111000000000011111111110000000000111111111100000000001111111111

Being 71 bits, and you're doing `Convert.ToIn64(result, 2);`, which is cutting it down to 64 bits. If the input and output are both strings, then why even do the conversion to an Int64 (a `long`)? Instead just `return result`

---

**Edit:** Just saw [Lasse V. Karlsen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/267/lasse-v-karlsen)'s comment which basically says the same